# need help on my choice of hardware for a pfSense router

Tags: hardware-rec, pfsense

I want to build the hardware for a pfSense router. I thought to use the following hardware:

mainboard: asus n3050m-e

- 2 x SATA 600 7-pin
- 1 x PCIe
- 1 x gigabit-ethernet Realtek RTL8111H
- 1 x ATX 12 V 4 pol
- 1 x Intel Celeron n3050 (1 x memory controller capable of handling
  max. 8 GB on 2 slots via a 240-pin DIMM connector)

RAM: kingston KVR16N11S8K2/8

- 2 x 4 GB DDR3RAM 1600 MHz 240-pin DIMM

SSD: patriot blast PBT240GS25SSDR

- 1 x 240 GB connected via SATA 600 7-pin

2nd Ethernet adapter: edimax, EN-9260TX-E, Gigabit Ethernet PCI Express Adapter

- 1 x gigabit-ethernet PCIe

I would like to know:

1.) how is the SSD drive powered? Over the SATA 600 7-pin connection or by a separate cable?

2.) By using Toms-Hardware guide and energy calculator, the estimated power need for the set-up is about 78W (MainBoard, 15W, CPU 55W, RAM 6W, SSD 1W, Ethernet 1W). Is that number realistic? Would it be possible to take a high-end note-book power-supply unit and to use the ATX 12 V 4 pol connector on the asus board to power the set-up 24/7? Would you have any recommendation of such a PSU?

3.) I thought to build the case out of wood and plexi glass. What would be an argument against a self made, electrical non conducting case? Evt. to not shield electromagnetic fields, from both sides?

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> 1.) how is the SSD drive powered? Over the SATA 600 7-pin connection or by a separate cable?

That specific SSD appears to be powered by a separate SATA power cable.

> 2.) By using Toms-Hardware guide and energy calculator, the estimated power need for the set-up is about 78W (MainBoard, 15W, CPU 55W, RAM 6W, SSD 1W, Ethernet 1W). Is that number realistic? Would it be possible to take a high-end note-book power-supply unit and to use the ATX 12 V 4 pol connector on the asus board to power the set-up 24/7? Would you have any recommendation of such a PSU?

The CPU wattage is overestimated. The TDP of that processor is 6w. The rest seems pretty within reason. You cannot take a laptop power supply and connect it directly to it but you could buy a PicoPSU.
i.e. [https://www.amazon.com/picoPSU-160-XT-DC-DC-Power-Converter-Module/dp/B005TWE6B8](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B005TWE6B8)

> 3.) I thought to build the case out of wood and plexi glass. What would be an argument against a self made, electrical non conducting case? Evt. to not shield electromagnetic fields, from both sides?

There's nothing wrong with building your own case, just be careful not to short anything with any metal components used.